# Videos only playing on page refresh in Safari

Tags: caching, video, safari, mp4, pageload

We're having issues with auto-playing the videos at the bottom of this page on Safari, both desktop and mobile:

http://dev-doublespace.pantheonsite.io/work/kdc-one/

The videos don't appear or play on the initial load of the page. If we click "Show controls", then the controls for the video appear, but the videos aren't available and the sizing of the video window is not correct (screenshot below). If we choose to copy the file address, then the proper mp4 file address shows. However, if we "open the video in new window", or re-load the page, the videos then appear and play as expected.

We assume this is some type of caching issue, but can't be certain.

This site was built on Wordpress and is being hosted on Pantheon. We have the Pantheon caching tool enabled. We're using the Beaver Builder page builder to maintain the page content.

If anyone has any ideas on what might be happening here and how we can resolve this, that would be greatly appreciated.

[image: initial load state]

Comment: does autoplay work if the video is in view rather than hidden at the bottom?

Comment: There was an issue with this on Safari in the past, but it was reportedly fixed now: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46585409/334402

Comment: Thanks for the feedback guys - confirming we have the most up-to-date version of Safari, so I don't think that is the issue. We ended up moving off of Pantheon onto a new hosting provider and the problem seems to have resolved itself, so I think we're all set.  Thanks again.